# Facebook in a Mac App

Tags: objective-c, facebook, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

how would I integrate Facebook into my Mac Application. I could give Objective-C a bit of a go, but it's going to be in an AppleScript-Objective-C project.

I could.. update the user's status a bit better instead of just opening their web browser and pointing them to "Facebook.com" , I could make my own interface that interacts with Facebook.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can interact with the Facebook API in many different ways, including submitting status updates as a POST request to the graph api. Their examples aren't at all language-specific. They demonstrate how to interact with it using curl on the command line, for instance.

Docs are here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

EDIT: Laziness IS one of the Three Virtues of the Programmer, but dude.... Clicking a link is too hard? Well, okay:

Here's how you authenticate your applications and get added as an application for a user:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/desktop

Then here's how to work the Graph api. The section you want is "Publishing" most of the way down the page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/

Comment: Can you give me a direct link to the curl examples?

Comment: @magikseb: If you are clever enough to create an AS-ObjC project, then you are clever enough to go to the site given, type `curl` into the search field, and see that examples are all over the place on the FB dev site.